# Why do we get ArrayTypeMismatch with ref params?

Tags: c#

**Given the scenerio:**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] covarientArray= new A[] { new A() };
        object polymorphism = new A();
        object test = covarientArray[0];
        M(ref polymorphism);//fine up to here

        M(ref covarientArray[0]);//ArrayTypeMismatchException
    }

    static void M(ref object o) { Console.WriteLine(o); }
}
class A {}
```

**And the definition of [ArrayTypeMisMatch:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception.aspx)**

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to store an
>   element of the wrong type within an array.

This Exception is thrown when an attemp is made **to store** an element of the wrong type within an array.  E.G.:

```
A[] invalid = new A[1];
invalid[0] = "";//I can't store a type of string within an array of type of A
```

How does this exception occur?  Why is it that we are doing a store operation when Invoking a method with a `ref` param?

Comment: I am shocked that arrays are covariant.

Comment: Imagine if `M` did something like this: `o = new B()`; all of a sudden your `covarientArray` which is actually an `A[]`, now contains an instance of `B` in its first element! EDIT: To answer your question, doing a `ref` when passing an array element _can_ replace that element altogether: it _is_ a store operation, at least potentially.

Comment: @KendallFrey You and me both. It flies in the face of what makes C# great. Eric Lippert has a post on it and why it was included: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx Maybe if the covariance additions in C#4.0 had existed since the C#1.0 days it'd be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that we are doing a store operation when Invoking a method
>   with a ref param?

Providing an array element as the argument to a `ref` parameter actually *is* a store operation, at least potentially. (Yeah, you might *not* reassign it, but the compiler/runtime doesn't necessarily *know* that)

Imagine if your `M` method implementation was this:

```
static void M(ref object o) 
{ 
    o = new B();
}
```

If we type your covariant array as `object[]` to so it compiles and works:

```
object[] covariantArray= new object[] { new A() };
M(ref covariantArray[0]);
Console.WriteLine(covariantArray[0].GetType().Name); //B
```

It runs and *replaced* the first element with a *new instance of B*. Of course, this is perfectly valid for an `object[]` array. So now if we simply change it to `A[]`:

```
object[] covariantArray= new A[] { new A() };
M(ref covariantArray[0]); //ArrayTypeMismatchException
Console.WriteLine(covariantArray[0].GetType().Name);
```

It throws the exception before the potentially dangerous/catastrophic/dogs-are-cats/up-is-down call to `M` is processed.

Of course, remove the `ref` calls or `ref` against a local variable instead of the array element and it works perfectly fine since you're not messing around with the array contents.

@hvd's answer is probably more correct in that it explains the underlying runtime mechanism for throwing, but at least here's a practical demonstration why it is so.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with the last sentence of my answer, `o = new B();` would otherwise need to check at runtime whether `o` really allows a `B` to be stored. Your answer is a lot clearer.

Comment: @hvd - Both answers have important info.  Too bad I cant choose 2.

Comment: @hvd +1 Question though: is this just an "optimization" step to avoid checking each assignment? As in, if you had `o = new A();` ten times in the method, it only does the check once instead of 10 times? Then without the "optimization" you _could_ pass a `ref` without assigning a value which should make calling `M` "ok", right? But if the runtime allowed the method to execute, the user instead would get the exception on the line `o = new B()`, which looking at the local context, seems like a really, really, really weird/bad place to be throwing an exception.

Comment: To me, "optimization" means it shouldn't change behaviour, but this clearly could if it was allowed otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I am not sure I understand your question. From the implementation's POV, I would not classify this as an optimisation, as throwing an exception is required of all implementations. From the CLR spec author's POV, I would classify this as an optimisation, since the spec *could* have said the check happens later.

Comment: @hvd Ooooh, ok, that makes more sense. Thanks for the info and perspective!

Answer (score 3):

The exception is also thrown when creating a `ref` to an array element of the wrong type. This is admittedly unclear by just reading the exception text, but it is very briefly mentioned indirectly on the page you linked to:

> The following Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) instructions throw ArrayTypeMismatchException :
>
> ldelema

[`ldelema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema.aspx) (load element address) is the instruction used to create a reference to an array element.

As for the why, it prevents *every* assignment to *every* `ref` argument from needing to do a run-time check of the type.